# iPhone code - using image in UIButton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to use an image in a UIButton `buttonHeader` background,
when i compile it i get an error that `buttonHeader` is not an image type, what property to use?

```
- (void)downloadImageHeader
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestWithBodyParams = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.../imageHeader.png"]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestWithBodyParams returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    buttonHeader = image;
}
```

Comment: Where is buttonHeader defined? What type is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the UIButton method

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
```

like

```
[buttonHeader setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: where is buttonHeader declared here?

Comment: @suse I guess it's a UIButton ivar that he uses in the example code. As he writes it's a UIButton in the text above the code.